# Treat last element differently when concatenating strings

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop

I made a loop for concatenating strings:

```
For cz As Integer = 0 To length - 1 Step +1
    result += GetChar(a, index) + " * 2^" & length - 1 & " + "
    index += 1
    length -= 1
Next cz
```

Is it possible to not add the "+" on the loop's last step?

I want to use some operations on that result but when i have "+" as last char I can't.

Comment: What is `length`? Is it just the length of `a`? What does the input look like?

Comment: @Ryan Yes, it's length of `a`. This is output: `1 * 2^5 + 0 * 2^4 + 1 * 2^3 + 0 * 2^2 + 1 * 2^1 + 0 * 2^0 +` I making something like tutorial "How to convert binary to decimal"

Comment: only add `"+"` if `cz < (length - 1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) will accomplish that for you if you pass it an enumerable of strings:

```
Dim result = String.Join(" + ",
    a.Select(Function (c, i) c & " * 2^" & (a.Length - 1 - i)))
```

Comment: How can i do math operation from result variable? I tried almost all.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Variable `result` is a String. `1 * 2^5 + 0 * 2^4 + 1 * 2^3 + 0 * 2^2 + 1 * 2^1 + 0 * 2^0` equals `42` (calculated in mind). But i don't know how to execute it in code. I tried `x = Convert.ToInt32(result)` but it's says wrong input format. Just i want something like: `1 * 2^5 + 0 * 2^4 + 1 * 2^3 + 0 * 2^2 + 1 * 2^1 + 0 * 2^0 = [result of this *, ^, + operations]`

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski: You can’t evaluate a string as VB.NET code easily (and that would be a terrible way to solve the problem, anyway). Parse the original as binary: `Convert.ToInt32(a, 2)`

Comment: Want to evaluate math "strings" in VB.NET. 

Acquire and make a reference to Interop.MSScriptControl.dll in your project

Then use something similar to below 
            Dim sc As New MSScriptControl.ScriptControl() With {.AllowUI = True, .Language = "VBScript"}
            MessageBox.Show(sc.Eval("(50 + 50) * 10 / 500").ToString)